# Only googlebots having error: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I had updated the AjaxControlToolkit from 3.5.51116.0 to 3.5.7.123 to get ride of this error: [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26752)

The above error is gone but according the site error log table googlebots are now having the following error randomly.

**Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.51116.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.**

Please note that site visitors are not having this error at all only googlebots having this error randomly and I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect AjaxControlToolkit assembly binding in web config from 3.5.51116.0 to 3.5.7.123 version: [<bindingRedirect> Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx)